# Fluentd can't push log of k8s on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd

I have a problem with my fluentd service.
the fluentd sent the logs from kubernetes pods , to a in instance of elasticsearch.
I have configured a daemonset with this setting:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logging
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logging
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-elasticsearch
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "elasticsearch"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER
            value: "elastic"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
            value: "changeme"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 1000Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf
          subPath: fluent.conf
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap: 
          name: fluentd-conf
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

**i have configured a fluent.conf as this:
**

```
# AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY, USE /templates/conf/fluent.conf.erb

@include "#{ENV['FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF'] || 'systemd'}.conf"
@include "#{ENV['FLUENTD_PROMETHEUS_CONF'] || 'prometheus'}.conf"
@include kubernetes.conf
@include conf.d/*.conf

<filter **>
   @type elasticsearch_genid
   hash_id_key _hash
</filter>
<match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**logging**>
  @type null
</match>
<match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**ingress**>
  @type null
</match>
<match **>
   @type elasticsearch
   @id out_es
   @log_level info
   include_tag_key true
   host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
   port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
   path "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PATH']}"
   scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}"
   ssl_verify "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY'] || 'true'}"
   ssl_version "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERSION'] || 'TLSv1'}"
   user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER']}"
   password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD']}"
   reload_connections "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_CONNECTIONS'] || 'false'}"
   reconnect_on_error "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RECONNECT_ON_ERROR'] || 'true'}"
   reload_on_failure "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_ON_FAILURE'] || 'true'}"
   log_es_400_reason "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_ES_400_REASON'] || 'false'}"
   logstash_prefix "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_PREFIX'] || 'logstash'}"
   logstash_format "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_FORMAT'] || 'true'}"
   index_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_INDEX_NAME'] || 'logstash'}"
   type_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_TYPE_NAME'] || 'fluentd'}"
**   <buffer>
     @type file
     path /fluentd/log/elastic-buffer
     flush_thread_count "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_THREAD_COUNT'] || '8'}"
     flush_interval "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_INTERVAL'] || '5s'}"
     chunk_limit_size "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_CHUNK_LIMIT_SIZE'] || '8M'}"
     queue_limit_length "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_QUEUE_LIMIT_LENGTH'] || '32'}"
     retry_max_interval "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_RETRY_MAX_INTERVAL'] || '30'}"
     flush_mode interval
     retry_forever true
   </buffer>**
   id_key _hash
   remove_keys _hash
</match>
```

after few minutes the logs of k8s are no longer sent to elasticsearch and I see this message on logs:

```
2023-06-28 06:59:19 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es] failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=65 next_retry_seconds=2023-06-28 06:59:51 +0000 chunk="5ff2b02d4fb312f14aaf84163ad37acd" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure error="could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"elasticsearch\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\"http\", :user=>\"elastic\", :password=>\"obfuscated\", :path=>\"\"}): read timeout reached
```

I understand that it is a buffer management problem... do you have an idea how I can solve it? maybe by changing some parameters

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you observe in logs whether there's a retry that was successful for chunk `5ff2b02d4fb312f14aaf84163ad37acd`? You might want to verify other such chunks too.